# Why is only one ImageView drawn to my Layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-drawable

I want to add multiple ImageView, that show a drawable, to a RelativeLayout. This short example should add two such ImageViews:

```
    //get drawable
    Drawable oval = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
    // set color
    oval.setColorFilter(imgEl.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    // create new image view
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    //set drawable and add to layout
    imageView.setImageDrawable(oval);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100));
    imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    mLayout.addView(imageView);


    //get drawable
    oval = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
    // set color
    oval.setColorFilter(imgEl.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    // create new image view
    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    //set drawable and add to layout
    imageView.setImageDrawable(oval);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100));
    imageView.setPadding(200,200,0,0);
    mLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Unfortunately, only the first one is shown, but the second one is not drawn on the screen. What is my mistake?

Comment: I believe it's because the second `ImageView` has a width and height of 100, but you're setting a left and top padding of 200, so its content is out of bounds. Did you mean to set margins instead of paddings? Those you would set on the `LayoutParams` instead.

Comment: Oh thanks, I confused `margin` and `padding`. Using a margin worked fine.